# Can I have SharePoint Foundation installed without IIS?

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepointfoundation2010

If I want to access only the document library of SharePoint Foundation from a .Net application (not a web app) using APIs (not web services), then is it possible to install SharePoint Foundation without IIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that IIS is a requirement, SharePoint won't even install without it.

Answer (score 2):

No. SharePoint is basically an IIS/ASP.Net HTTP module and request handler.